# Copy and paste graphics - Function - photo is not copied

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good morning.

Again, I have to ask for your help.

The script I am writing is to perform the following action:

1. take the tabs from the worksheet that are selected (Select in the "Source 1" sheet)
2. copy everything into the Paste sheet
3. On the basis of the 'Paste' sheet - Create a new file with all the
   content (skip marked sheets)

What I managed to do has some shortcomings, such as:

1. No loop to collect and copy the marked sheets
2. No parameter copy only styles and values (skip functions)

But what worries me the most is that the **photo is not copied.**

```
function copyAndPaste(){

    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Source 1");
    //Logger.log(ss.getRange(3, 8).getValue())
    Logger.log("LastColumn "+ss.getLastColumn());
    Logger.log("LastRow "+ss.getLastRow());
    Logger.log(ss.getDataRange());
    var ssRange = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation();
    var ssRange_ = "A1:"+ssRange;
    var select = ss.getRange(ssRange_)
    var destSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Paste");
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
    select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
    select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: false});

}
```

[My work filee](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mVsVTshId6m7t61m_2_H9ZqgZKDz9jjxBh_l8C5BOAo/edit?usp=sharing)

Edit 20.07.2018

This is the code, This is the code which is supposed to clean up the validation of data in cells but gets an error.

```
function copyAndPaset(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var spreadsheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Modified
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Source 1");// Modified

  var copiedSheet = ss.copyTo(spreadsheet).setName("Paste"); // Added
  copiedSheet.clearContents(); // Added

  var ssRange = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation();
  var ssRange_ = "A1:"+ssRange;
  var select = ss.getRange(ssRange_)

  var destSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Paste");
  var destSheetRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow(), destSheet.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation(); // I added but will get an error
  var destSheetRange_ ="A1:"+destSheetRange; // Added
  var destRangeClear = destSheet.getRange(destSheetRange_); // Added
  destRangeClear.clearDataValidations() // Added


  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  //select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: false}); // When this is run, the merged cells are cleared.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no methods for retrieving images on Spreadsheet yet. So how about this workaround? The flow of this workaround is as follows.

#### Flow :

1. Duplicate "Source 1" to the same Spreadsheet as the sheet name of "Paste".

   - By this, images on "Source 1" can be copied.
2. Remove contents on the copied sheet ("Paste") using `clearContents()`.

   - By this, values on the sheet are removed. But the images are not removes.
3. Using your script, the contents are copied to "Paste".

#### Modified script :

```
function copyAndPaset(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var spreadsheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Modified
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Source 1");// Modified
  var copiedSheet = ss.copyTo(spreadsheet).setName("Paste"); // Added
  copiedSheet.clearContents(); // Added

  var ssRange = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation();
  var ssRange_ = "A1:"+ssRange;
  var select = ss.getRange(ssRange_)
  var destSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Paste");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: false}); // When this is run, the merged cells are cleared.
}
```

#### Note :

- **Before you use this script, please rename or remove the existing "Paste" sheet.**
- In your script, it seems that the action is the same with `var copiedSheet = ss.copyTo(spreadsheet).setName("Paste");`. Because I thought that you might want to put other values instead of the duplication, I used `clearContents()` after the sheet was copied.
- When `select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: false})` of your script is used, the merged cells are cleared. If you want this situation, please use it. If you want to keep the merged cells, please remove this script.

#### References :

- [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [clearContents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearContents())

If this workaround was not what you want, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

The error occurs because both `destSheet.getLastRow()` and `destSheet.getLastColumn()` are 0. `getRange(0, 0)` occurs error. So I modified the script as follows.

```
function copyAndPaset(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var spreadsheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Modified
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Source 1");// Modified

  var copiedSheet = ss.copyTo(spreadsheet).setName("Paste"); // Added
  copiedSheet.clearContents(); // Added

  var ssRange = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation();
  var ssRange_ = "A1:"+ssRange;
  var select = ss.getRange(ssRange_)

  var destSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Paste");

  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1); // Moved
  select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true}); // Moved

  var destSheetRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow(), destSheet.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation(); // I added but will get an error
  var destSheetRange_ ="A1:"+destSheetRange; // Added
  var destRangeClear = destSheet.getRange(destSheetRange_); // Added
  destRangeClear.clearDataValidations() // Added

  //select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: false}); // When this is run, the merged cells are cleared.
}
```

Comment: You have nothing to apologize for.
First of all, thank you for showing us how to use **clearContents()** with **copiedSheet ()**.
That made me think...
I've analyzed your fixes, and read the notes and we're close to success.
Once we have copied everything, I would like to clear the cells that are suspending validations.
I have found 
[link] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear(Object)

And I added 
 `destSheet.clear({validationsOnly: true});`
but it doesn't work

Comment: @Arkadiusz K. I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I think that the reason that your issue was not resolved is due to my incomplete answer. ``clear({validationsOnly: true})`` is the method of class Range. [Ref.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear(Object)) So when you use this, please use like ``destSheet.getRange(ssRange_).clear({validationsOnly: true})``. I thought that in your situation, you might want such script.

Comment: @Arkadiusz K. If this was not what you want, can you provide your current script, because I have no information of it? If you can do, please add it to your question. And if the sample input and output you want are added, I think that it helps my to think of your solution.

Comment: Tanaike Everything is fine. Don't worry ;) Your solution is great.
It wasn't me who wrote that he wanted to clean the cells where there was a correctness check, leaving only the values. 
While reading the documentation, I assumed that 
`select.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});`
Will settle the matter A code must be added to the logic which, before copying the values, cleans the cells in the "paset" tab from the correctness check by means of
 `clearDataValidations();`

Comment: @Arkadiusz K. I'm sorry I couldn't understand what you want. Can you provide a sample sheet before and after the copy you want? By this, I think that I can understand what you want. I'm sorry for taking your time.

Comment: [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mVsVTshId6m7t61m_2_H9ZqgZKDz9jjxBh_l8C5BOAo/edit#gid=1100910768  This is a link to the sheet that contains your fixes, and I added a piece of code that is supposed to clean up the validation of data in cells but gets an error.

Comment: @Arkadiusz K. Thank you for the sample. From the sample sheet, it is found that the error occurs because both ``destSheet.getLastRow()`` and ``destSheet.getLastColumn()`` are 0. ``getRange(0, 0)`` occurs error. I would like to resolve your issue. But I cannot still understand what you want to do. When the sample of input is the sheet of "Source 1", can you provide the sample of output? If you can do, can you share the output sample? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @ I don't know if I did it according to the rules of the forum, but I edited my question, added current versions of the script.

Comment: @Arkadiusz K. I update my answer. Could you please confirm it? I cannot still understand what you want to do. So that is not what you want, I'm really sorry. At that time, can you provide the sample output you want? I would like to resolve your issue.

Comment: Tanaike Thank you very much.
This is what I'm going for. Now I have only to write a loop that will create more such sheets. Thank you again for your patience and help. Have a nice day

Comment: @Arkadiusz K. Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was solved. I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.